# Did Romance languages evolve in Pannonia?

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin, romance-languages, romanization

As a sister question of [Did Romance languages evolve in North Africa?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26302/did-romance-languages-evolve-in-north-africa), I would like to ask what was the situation in [Pannonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pannonia) was there a [Pannonian Romance Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pannonian_Romance) and what research is there to it's existence? At least parts of the romanized populations along the Danube stayed after the Romans ceded some parts of [Pannonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pannonia) to the Huns in 433. The Huns later conquered more of Pannonia before their empire collapsed. The control of the area was unstable with the Goths, Gepids, Lombards, Avars, Franks, Bulgars and Magyars seizing control. The Franks documented, around 800, after their victory against [the Avars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlemagne#Avar_campaigns) that there was a Latin population in Pannonia with priests that had no hierarchy or guidance from Rome. The Magyars (Hungarians) list Roman pastoralists as one of the populations in the areas when they took control in the [Gesta Hungarorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesta_Hungarorum). Is there any more thorough analysis of [Pannonian Romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pannonian_Romance)? Texts? Word lists? Research?

Comment: The Wikipedia page “Pannonian Romanc Language” you cite in your first sentence seems to answer your question. I am puzzled to what you are actually asking.

Comment: I am rewriting that wikipedia page. I am asking here, if anyone here has some more in depth information. I modelled my question off of the Romance in North Africa question.